# Image as a href to modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with JS. I mean when user click on the image, modal opens, I must use a href. I don't know how to make that working. I have only modal. I show you my code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<article class="item">
  <a href="???" class="image fit"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" id="myBtn" alt="" /></a>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: If I understand you correctly (if you need open modal and go to another page), you can also can add `var win = window.open(url, '_blank');` to you image click handler. This is bad solution, but it should works

Comment: I want to make this modal something like a popup. Not to open new page or window. And when I will close this window I can click outside this modal. I must do something similar to that.

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` eg `btn.onclick = function(e) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
 e.preventDefault();
}`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC ok i used it, but what href i must type to open this modal when i click on the image?

Comment: use `<a href="#"`

Comment: No it isn't working. When I click on the image pages go to the top when I set ahref = #

Comment: show your issue in jsfiddle/codepen

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time to understand what you want to accomplish, but I guess you look for something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="image fit"><img src="images/film/min_1.png" id="myBtn" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: When I put "javascript:;" nothing happens :(

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information. In the above mentioned fiddle by kevin b. everything seems to work and when you change href="#" to href="javascript:;" the issue with the scrolling is also resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I got it working by setting the href to '#' (see [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hqb9vqve/))

```
<a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/film/min_1.png" id="myBtn" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: No, it isn't working.When I set a href=# page goes to the top

Comment: In that case I think you haven't provided all the needed code, since it is working in the jsFiddle demo. Could you please provide more markup please?

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

On image click you are showing modal, change it to none, and you can navigate to your given url in href

Comment: But href I mean to open modal. I want when user click on image (image is a href) and after clicking at  the image modal opens

Answer (score -1):

I know that the question was posted years ago but I struggled to find proper answer for a while. Actually, you can make this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="your-modal-id" class="image fit">
  <img src="" id="" alt="" />
</a>
```

Hope someone will find it helpful)

Comment: please be more elaborate - this alone doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I don't intended to answer this particular question that was posted 3 years ago... This is a way to make "Image as a href to modal". In order to implement this code to the code of the author he just needs to put his values in appropriate fields. Please, be more attentive during commenting any answers.